# How to grant a permission to an app?

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow

I have an LG G4 with Android 6.0. I installed an application for learning English. The app requires me to watch a video and then to speak. However, I'm having trouble with the latter.

This is the error message:

> In order for the app to work properly, please enable access to the microphone from your phone settings.

What should be done to make the application work?

Comment: Settings app -> Apps -> your  app -> Permissions -> enable Microphone or relevant permissions. Have you tried that already? And, link the app. If it is designed for Android 6 it should have asked you to grant that permission.

Comment: I don't find this , please can you show me using pictures

Comment: I don't have an LG G4. Can you go to the app's page where you can force stop it? If yes, you might be having the option about permissions. If you don't, do a web search.

Comment: For all the shortcomings of this question, that's a brilliant title! Unfortunately, I have to make this question more useful, so I will edit it to make it more informative. As consolation, have a +1.

Comment: Although Android Marshmallow should ask that each time it requests to use microphone, please include the link to the app, so we can test it. You might have set to always disable it.

Comment: Thanks  for you all, I found the solution, please take a look at the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Twilight application which is running, you need only to make stop and then give the permissions to the English application and then you can run the Twilight app.